# Uncertain about definition of Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian-network

If I have a Bayesian network of the form:

$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow D$

is it necessarily true that $P(B,D|C)=P(B|C)P(D|C)$?

Wikipedia gives the following defining condition for a Bayes net: 'variable is conditionally independent of its non-descendants given its parent variables', where non-descendant means no direct arrow connecting the random variables.

On the left-hand side of the above equation, one conditions on the only parent of $D$, which is $C$. So $D$ should be conditionally independent of $B$, even though no conditioning on the parents of $B$ takes places, yes?

Comment: Yes. $B$ is a non-descendant of $D$.  So $B$ is conditionally independent of $D$ when given $C$ (the parent of $D$).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks. Logically this makes sense, but I wasn't sure if I could trust Wikipedia on this one since I'm used to formal statements.